# Запуск программы с правами администратора без ввода пароля

Tags: bat

Решил написать батник, который запускает программы с правами администратора, но на моменте, когда он требует ввести пароль, я не могу ничего ввести, клавиатура просто отказывается что-либо писать.

Выполняется задача из под другой учётной записи, у которой нет прав админа. Доступ к админской учётке есть, пароль обязателен.

Хочется понять:

1. Почему не работает клава в этот момент?
2. Как сделать возможным "тихого" запуска этого батника, без ввода пароля? (Вшить его в батник)

На данный момент выглядит всё так:

```
runas.exe /profile /user:Admin "путь_до_файла"
timeout /t 3
runas.exe /profile /user:Admin "путь_до_файла"
timeout /t 3
runas.exe /profile /user:Admin "путь_до_файла"
```

Comment: *Как сделать возможным "тихого" запуска этого батника, без ввода пароля?* `/savecred`. Один раз ввести, и дальше само будет работать. Вот только юзер, если умный, получит возможность запустить любой процесс от админа таким же способом.

Comment: Ещё вариант - создать ярлык к батнику, и в нём указать запуск от имени администратора - при сохранении ярлыка ввести пароль. Тогда runas вообще не понадобится.